# Laravel 5 and weird bug: curly braces on back

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel-5

Whenever I go back in history on my Laravel website, the response I see is this:

```
{}
```

When I go forward to where I was before that, it shows those braces as well.

The problem doesn't occur if I launch Developer Tools in Chrome with Disable Cache option. The `Content-Type` of what's returned is indeed `application/json`. In Firefox there's no such problem.

It happens because one of my Middlewares. I wrote AjaxJson middleware to translate all Ajax requests to JSON response. Weirdly, when I go back in history, Google Chrome makes this request Ajax. It contains this header:

> X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

And therefore `$request->ajax()` returns `true`.

This is my middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class AjaxJson
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        if (!$request->ajax()) {
            return $response;
        }

        if (!$response instanceof Response) {
            return $response;
        }

        return response()->json($response->getOriginalContent(), $response->status());
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

## UPDATE

I found out about `no-store` value for `Cache-Control` response header. It prevents Chrome from using cache when clicking back button. I created a middleware to set `Cache-Control` like this:

> Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, no-cache, no-store

Please let me know guys, if you know better way of solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to process the request after validations:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        return response()->json($response->getOriginalContent(), $response->status());
    }

    return $next($request);        
}
```

Comment: How is this different than what I did?

Comment: There are two types of middleware: 1. Middlewares called before request arrives at controllers. 2. Middleware called after request arrives at controllers. So calling `$next($request);` immediately in the handle method is applying the middleware after all.

Comment: Ok now I see your point. The problem was something entirely different though, I will update this topic soon.