# Should Ajax actions REALLY have separate URL?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, http, http-headers

Every now and then I hear an opinion that having the same URL for non-Ajax and Ajax action is bad.

On my app, I'm having forms that are sent with Ajax for better user experience. For people who disable JavaScript, my forms work too. Same goes with some of my links. I used to have the same URL for both and just use appropriate content and `Content-Type`, according to whether it's an Ajax call or not. This caused problem with Google Chrome: [Laravel 5 and weird bug: curly braces on back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37556431/laravel-5-and-weird-bug-curly-braces-on-back)

My question now is - is this REALLY bad idea to have the same URL for Ajax and non-Ajax actions? It's painful to make two separate URLs for each of those actions. Or maybe is there a good workaround to manage caching? In theory, one header can change the behavior entirely, so I don't see why should I create extra layer of my app and force the same thing to have separate URL.

Please share your opinions.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP is flexible and allows you to *design* the resources the way you want. You *design* the APIs and *designing* comes to personal preferences. But in this case, having one resource that responds to different types of request is absolutely fine. This is why the HTTP headers like `Content-type` exists.

And for the caching you can use [HTTP Etag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) header. It's a caching header that forces the client to *validate* the cached resources before using them.

> The ETag or entity tag is part of HTTP, the protocol for the World Wide Web. It is one of several mechanisms that HTTP provides for web cache validation, which allows a client to make conditional requests. This allows caches to be more efficient, and saves bandwidth, as a web server does not need to send a full response if the content has not changed

Comment: HTTP is flexible, I agree. But unfortunetely, some of this greatness is bitterly screwed up by browsers, like in this case.

Comment: @RoboRobok Yes, the way Chrome caches the resources and HTTP redirects is really _annoying_.